# Boot from live Tails SD card on Mac OSX El Capitan

Tags: uefi, liveusb, osx-el-capitan, tails

Goal: Boot into Tails from an SD card on a Macbook Air running El Capitan.

Specs: Macbook Air, 8Gb RAM, i5, Running OSX 10.11 "El Capitan".

**Solutions tried and problems with each:**

1. Follow [Tails instructions](https://tails.boum.org/doc/first_steps/installation/manual/mac/index.en.html) for Mac OSX

   - **Problem:** After everything is done, reboot, only the Mac HD shows up
2. Use rEFInd (v0.9.2):

   - Created two partitions on the SD card, with a GUID Partition Table (GTP). Both Journaled (HFS+).

     - /dev/disk2s2 - Tails (dd'd following the instructions from 1.)
     - /dev/disk2s3 - rEFInd: `./install.sh --alldrivers --ownhfs /dev/disk2s3` (Also tried without the `--alldrivers` flag)
   - **Problem:** rEFInd option shows up when rebooting. After selecting it I get three options: Boot Mac OSX, boot Tails (has the Tails logo), or boot legacy BIOS Tails (just shows a windows-like logo in grey).

     - If I select the one with the Tails logo, it goes to a new screen that says:

       ```
       rEFInd - Booting OS

       Starting bootx64.efi
       Using load options ''
       Failed to read blocks: 0x2
       ```

       I have already tried erasing the Tails partition and redoing it a couple of times, with the same output.
     - If I select the one that says `legacy BIOS Tails...` I get a black screen that says the usual `No bootable devices found... Insert one and press any key to continue`.

Let me know if there is anything missing that could help debug this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually found the issue, I had formatted the partition where I put Tails as an ExFAT partition, which doesn't work even though it shows up on the boot menu.

Formatting it as FAT fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just guessing here, but a conversation on Mac rumors recomends not using units on the dd bs parameter, so try the guide again using bs=16000000 instead of bs=16m.

Comment: Just tried, but got the same error: `Faile to read blocks: 0x2`... I think I'll try with a different distro to make sure it's not the tails image. And possibly with a usb stick instead of an sd card

Comment: Have you checked the checksums on the image? Even if it checks out, you may want to re-download the iso, preferably over a wired connection.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention I had checked that, I eventually found the problem, posting as an answer now, thanks for the help though!